# viewport scaling works on image width but not height

Tags: css, viewport, scaling

I can't get [this simple slideshow](http://tests.markgarvey.com/) to re-size correctly. When I shrink down the window, the image width compresses, but the height does not, and I want the height/width ratio to remain the same as the viewport shrinks. I know the fault lies somewhere in my CSS, and but I can't track down the issue. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `height: auto`

```
.slides img {
  height: auto;
  /* Rest of you code */
}
```